# Using R and Rvest to scrape google page problem with http_nodes

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape search results from google... I'm trying to get the link from this section:

```
<a href="https://commercialprojectservices.com.au/about/" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://commercialprojectservices.com.au/about/&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjxhtOJ4erkAhVj7XMBHX8hC1EQFjABegQIABAB"><h3 class="LC20lb"><div class="ellip">About » Commercial Project Services</div></h3><br><div class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30 bc">https://commercialprojectservices.com.au › about</cite></div></a>
```

but when I do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
hp <- "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=commercial+project+site%3A.com.au&oq=commercial+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.3707j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
a <- read_html(hp)
b <- html_nodes(a, "div > div > a")
c <- html_attr(b, "href")
```

`b[16]` results in:

```
b[16]
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <a href="/url?q=https://commercialprojectservices.com.au/scaffold-mananagement/quote/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwib3_i48OrkAhUS4KYKHSdzDhYQFjAIegQIBRAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw3blXNQKZnL8P1U-ntgVagX"> ...
```

The `href` part seems to have been set to the `"ping="` part of the line...

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google was sending me garbage because they didn't like my user agent (curl)

faked my user agent and it works now

Comment: To be honest, the first link I then tried to reach wouldn't work. It was a WordPress site and sent me to Captcha. So now I'm looking at Rselenium.